# Regex split a multiline string using \

Tags: c#, regex, split, multiline

I have tried approximately every possible combination of RegexOptions.MultiLine and escaped backslashes in order to split a text using \ as a separator.

I have this text:

```
The quick brown
Fox jumps\
Over the
Lazy dog\
```

I want to split it into

```
The quick brown
Fox jumps\
```

and

```
Over the
Lazy dog\
```

I have tried so far (together with a call to the Split method of the Regex):

```
Regex regexSplit = new Regex(@"\\$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Regex regexSplit = new Regex(@"\$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Regex regexSplit = new Regex(@"\\$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Regex regexSplit = new Regex(@"\$", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Regex regexSplit = new Regex(@"\\$");
Regex regexSplit = new Regex(@"\$");
```

Every time I get back the complete original string.
Could you give me a hand please?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I removed an extra space.
The reason why I need to use a Regex is because a \ might be inside a match enclosed in "" or ''.
This is why I need to match on end of line as well.

I must add that `\\$` works when I test the expression using RegexBuddy and the same input text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You have an extra space at "Fox jumps\ " so `@"\\$"` won't match. Either remove the space or use `@"\\"` to split. You can also check for spaces `@"\\\s*$"`.</strike>

This one should do the trick :

```
var results = Regex.Split(subject, @"\\\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the extra space.

Comment: It is working! I must add that I am not convinced that there is whitespace between the \ and the end of line in that case. Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Why not this simple string split:

```
        string s = "The quick brown\r\nFox jumps\\\\r\n Over the\r\nLazy dog\\";
    s.Split(new string[] { "\\\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: He might be interested to split only if \ is at the end of line.

Comment: This way you are not taking into account all the possible EOL combinations like `\r` and `\n` but only the windows-style `\r\n`. Regex `$` is much safer to use.